# Is useState hook related to hoisting?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm fairly new to React.js/javascript and are working on a new project, I would like to be able to manually update my component (due to some 3rd party library limitations) when needed.

After searching I modified a pattern from [official site](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#is-there-something-like-forceupdate) that seems to meets my need by utilizing the useState hook (Though it's not recommended). Below is an extremely simplified component for testing, useRef is needed in my scenario.

What I'm wondering is why the update function can be called properly in useRef, does this have sth to do with hoisting, or it's more of a react thing, such as the execution sequence of hooks are modified under the hood?

https://codesandbox.io/s/useref-usestate-test-0x0hhb?file=/src/App.js

```
import {useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'

export default function App() {
  const testRef = useRef(()=>{
    console.log('testRef called');
    update({});
  })

  const [, update]= useState({});

  useEffect(()=>{
    console.log('updated'); 
  });
  
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>
        <button onClick={()=>testRef.current()}>
          Test
        </button>
      </h2>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a ref at all? Can you not use `onClick={() => update({})}`

Comment: @Phil  I should have mentioned that this is an extremly simplified version just to illustrate my question only, in my use case useRef is needed and not called on button click event as well .  Still, thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: @Phil Thanks for the reference, but i'm afraid the link doesn't completely answer my question. Appreciated

Comment: How does it not? It literally has the same thing with a function that references a `const` declared after the function.

Comment: The link does provide some explanation on the behavior, but given that I'm asking for clarification if it's related to hoisting or any react hook mechanism, to me this fallacy isn't completely clarified. That's why i'd say it **doesn't completely** answer. Still, I can't thank you more for helping. Really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not about hoisting or React doing anything under the hood – `update` is a name in the scope that `useRef` closes over. (It could just as well be a name in another scope, or it could be undefined. Doesn't quite matter.) In fact, as the example below shows, this is just JavaScript and nothing React specific.

There would only be an issue if you called `testRef.current()` before the `const [, update] = ...` line (since `g` is in the [Temporal Dead Zone](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let#temporal_dead_zone_tdz)):

```
function x() {
    const f = () => {
        g();
    };
    f();
    const g = () => console.log("ok");
}

x();
```

throws

```
VM471:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'g' before initialization
    at f (<anonymous>:3:9)
    at x (<anonymous>:5:5)
    at <anonymous>:9:1
```

but

```
function x() {
    const f = () => {
        g();
    };
    const g = () => console.log("ok");
    f();
}

x();
```

just prints

```
ok
```

as you'd expect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! But with my little knowledge about js by far, when the scope of useRef is established, I get your point update is included and in TDZ, then update is actually assigned a anonymous function with useState. Does that mean that the scope of useRef is updated?

Comment: No, the scope (as such) is not updated, but the name `g` (or `update` in your case) is assigned an actual value. In the TDZ, the name exists but has no value (not even `undefined`).

Comment: Not familiar with scope/TDZ and did some research yet still a bit confused, may I conclude that: 

**1.** `update`  first enters TDZ when the scope `useRef` established, and no error will be raised cause it is not invoked.

**2.** Then within the parent scope (`App` in my sample) `update` is initialized by `useState`. 

**3.** Called with `testRef.current()`, and with scope chaining update is able to access the function initialized by `useState`